# Find $\limsup _{n\to \infty } \sqrt [n] {n^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

**Question :**

> Find : $$\limsup _{n\to \infty } \sqrt [n] {n^{2}}$$

I think, the limit is $1$. But, how can I show? Can you give a hint?

Comment: I guess you mean $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} ,$$right?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes. I mean this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the limit exists, you can just use standard limit gymnastics:
$$
L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{2/n}\implies\log L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{2/n}\log n=0\implies L=e^0=1
$$
What we used: Continuity of logarithm and L'Hôpital's or just knowing that $n$ beats $\log n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \sqrt[n]{n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 \ln n}{n} = 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2} = e^0 = 1$. Because the limit exists, the limit superior must also exist (and equal the limit).

Comment: The "monotonically decreasing" argument is offtopic.